# .NET Core 2 on azure portal

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-core-2.0

Is there a setting on the azure portal to run .NET Core 2? I migrated our code base to run on .NET Core 2 from .NET Core 1.1.4. However, on the portal, I only see options to select .NET Framework v3.5 and v4.7

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd" Handling ASP.NET
>   Core Web Application deployment. D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5):
>   warning : Using DotNetCliToolReference to reference
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet' is obsolete and can be
>   removed from this project. This tool is bundled by default in the .NET
>   Core SDK. [D:\local\repository\TFA\TFA.csproj] D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300-rc1-008673\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets(33,5):
>   warning : Using DotNetCliToolReference to reference
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools' is obsolete and can be
>   removed from this project. This tool is bundled by default in the .NET
>   Core SDK. [D:\local\repository\TFA\TFA.csproj]   Restore completed in
>   763.12 ms for D:\local\repository\TFA\TFA.csproj.   Restoring packages for D:\local\repository\TFTests\TFTests.csproj...
>   D:\local\repository\TFTests\TFTests.csproj : warning NU1603:
>   Faker.NETCore 1.0.1 depends on NETStandard.Library (>= 1.4.0) but
>   NETStandard.Library 1.4.0 was not found. An approximate best match of
>   NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 was resolved. [D:\local\repository\TF.sln]
>   D:\local\repository\TFTests\TFTests.csproj : error NU1201: Project TFA
>   is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1).
>   Project TFA supports: netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
>   [D:\local\repository\TF.sln]   Restore failed in 6.14 sec for
>   D:\local\repository\TFTests\TFTests.csproj.   Restore completed in
>   113.64 ms for D:\local\repository\TFA\TFA.csproj. Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\local\repository\TF.sln" An error has
>   occurred during web site deployment. \r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\73.10510.3399\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
>   "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

I found another stackOverflow post that says I have to delete my wwwroot directory before deploying due some possible net1.1 lingering files. I'm going to try that next

EDIT:
The deployment seems to be failing because of `Faker.NETCore`.
However, I have no idea what this is. It's not being used anywhere in our app. Is this a lingering library from .NET Core 1.1

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: is throwing any error? You don't need to select an specific framework. With 4.7 it's ok.

Comment: Yeah, the merge is failing to deploy.

```Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "D:\local\repository\TF.sln"```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was my testSuite failing. I had to bring that up to 2.0 as well. I'm not sure if delete the deployment cache in tools through the kudo console or wiping out my wwwroot folder helped. But I also did that because of other posts.